# File With Same Name From different folder in ios

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using "xcode 6.1.1" and "cocos2dx-3.2".
I need to access same file name from different folder.
In Resource i have 3 folder "A,B and C" and all this folder contain image with same name "1.png".
If i need to access 1.png of folder "A" ,How i can do this in cocos2dx please help?
following code is working fine in Android but not working in iOS

```
helpImage->setTexture("A/1.png");
```

Thanks.

Comment: In Android same images name can be copied to separate folders & accessible but if you try adding same name image in Xcode then it will not allow to add because while adding you are adding images in resources of project...So it is not possible in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't used cocos for some time now, but it is pretty easy to do.

Do this:
Prepare directory with your game data. Here lets call it "GameData". Pick name you like.
Drag and drop that directory to the xcode, probably best location is Supporting files. Dialog will show up. Select "Create folder references", deselect copy if needed.

And basically you are done. During build process all resources will be copied to bundle with paths as is in that directory "GameData". So you can have files with same name without problems.